# How to send the visual created in FabricJS

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

Being that I am a beginner with JS, I'll do my best to keep the question concise.

I'd like to use the http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing/ and have the ability for users to send me an email with the graphic created.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Canvas has the toDataURL(options) function:

```
var pngData = canvas.toDataURL('png');
```

You can then send that back to your server via Ajax and send e-mail in whatever way you're used to.